# Flask - difference between methods for detecting 'POST'?

Tags: flask

When i want to check if form data was submitted using `POST`, what is the difference between:

`if request.method == 'POST'`

And:

`if form.validate_on_submit():`

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form.validate_on_submit()` does what the `request.method == 'POST'` and more, so it's like a more advanced function.

`form.validate_on_submit()` is a function implemented in the **"Flask-WTF"** package, which is a shortcut to two functions: `form.is_submitted()` and `form.validate()`

```
    def validate_on_submit(self):
        """Call :meth:`validate` only if the form is submitted.
        This is a shortcut for ``form.is_submitted() and  form.validate()``.
        """
        return self.is_submitted() and self.validate()
```

Note: The `self.validate()` is implemented by the **"wtforms"** package, which **"Flask-WTF"** uses the `wtforms.Form` as a base class for the `flask_wtf.FlaskForm` or the `flask_wtf.Form` which is deprecated.

Going deeper, what the `self.is_submitted()` function does is return a `_is_submitted()` boolean function:

```
def is_submitted(self):
    """Consider the form submitted if there is an active request and
    the method is ``POST``, ``PUT``, ``PATCH``, or ``DELETE``.
    """

    return _is_submitted()
```

And the `_is_submitted()` is defined as:

```
def _is_submitted():
    """Consider the form submitted if there is an active request and
    the method is ``POST``, ``PUT``, ``PATCH``, or ``DELETE``.
    """

    return bool(request) and request.method in SUBMIT_METHODS
```

The `SUBMIT_METHODS` constant is defined this way:

```
SUBMIT_METHODS = set(('POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'))
```

From the snippets, you can see that the `form.validate_on_submit()` handles the `request.method` and does more.

So if you are making use of the **Flask-WTF** package and your form is inheriting from the *"FlaskForm"* class, it's better to use `form.validate_on_submit()` than `request.method == 'POST'`, as the former handles both verifying if a form is submitted and if the post request made is also valid.